# An urn contains $8$ red balls and $12$ black balls and $10$ are removed at random?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> An urn contains $8$ red balls and $12$ black balls and $10$ are removed at random. Find the probability that $7$ black balls are removed. Hint: Use binomials to count the number of ways to get $7$ black and $3$ red balls.

Please help!

Comment: The [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) counts the number of ways to choose $k$ elements from $n$ when order doesn't matter. So how many ways to choose 7 black balls? 3 red balls? 10 balls?

Comment: A friendly reminder, in questions like this it is okay to temporarily assume that the balls are labeled.  Further, it is safe to assume that when pulling a ball it is done in an unbiased manner (each of the twenty available balls are equally likely to be pulled) otherwise the question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are $12\choose 7$ ways to select the 7 black balls out of the 12 black balls, and similarly $8 \choose 3$ for the red ones, the probability would be the product of both of these divided by the total possibilities of choosing a ball from the urn, which is $20 \choose 10$.

Therefore, the probability should be 
$${12\choose 7} {8\choose 3} \over {20\choose 10} $$
That works out to be $1008\over 4199$

Comment: You are correct.  However, I think you should explain how you arrived at your answer.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.